# R markdown toc_depth only certain level

Tags: r, markdown

in R markdown you can set table of content by this code.

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
---
```

This way also 1st level of depth is included. I'm curious if there is a way how to set toc_debth ONLY to 2.

Comment: There is a workaround. Don't keep anything in R Markdown document, which has "Heading 1" format. If your document is separated by only "Heading 2" formats, then this should be possible. But then it will not look aesthetically appealing. It's your call finally.